# C++ assignment that requires a tricky while loop at the end

Tags: c++, while-loop

Is there some way to write a condition within a while loop that creates output if the user guesses a number that is within 10 units (plus or minus) from a random number generated by the program (integers)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    srand ( time(NULL) );

    bool valid;
    int randNum;
    int sum = 0;
    int userNum;

    for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++)
    {

    randNum = rand() % (71) + 7;

    cout << "Random number " << x << ":  " << randNum << endl;

    sum = sum + randNum;
    
    }

    cout << "\nThe total of all the random numbers is " << sum << "\n\n";
        
    cout << "Guess a number between 70 and 770:  ";

    do
    {

    cin >> userNum;

    while(userNum >= 70 && userNum <= 770)
    {
        while(userNum == sum)
        {
            cout << "You win";
            break;
        }

        while(/* the number given by the user is within 10 units from the random number generated by the program*/)
        {
            cout << "You almost won";
            break;
        }
        break;
    }    

    while(userNum < 70 || userNum > 770)
    {
        cout << "Try again.";
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
    
    } 
    while (!valid);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I already realize now that my loop will run infinitely if i put the correct number in. so if i put valid = true; within the while(userNum == sum) loop, it wont produce infinite output, but it wont end the program either.

Comment: i've been specifically instructed to use while loops at the end.i'm not sure if i'll lose points for using a do/while loop first. i wasn't sure how to even do the last part without using a do/while loop instead of strictly while loops

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have to `#include <stdlib.h>` then for the condition in your while loop you write `abs(userNum - randNum) <= 10`. This will give the magnitude of the difference between the userNum and randNum, which you want to be less than or equal to 10.